# apply custom function to an existing column to output multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my starting df:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['alpha', 'beta'], columns = ['text'])
df
    text
0   alpha
1   beta
```

Here is the end result I want:

```
    text    first           second          third
0   alpha   alpha-first     alpha-second    alpha-third
1   beta    beta-first      beta-second     beta-third
```

I have written the custom function `parse()`, no issue there:

```
def parse(text):
    return [text + ' first', text + ' second', text + ' third']
```

Now I try to apply `parse()` to the initial df, which is where errors arise:

1) If I try the following:

```
df = df.reindex(columns = list(df.columns) + ['first', 'second', 'third']) # Create empty columns    
df[['first', 'second', 'third']] = df.text.apply(parse)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

2) Slightly different version:

```
df = df.reindex(columns = list(df.columns) + ['first', 'second', 'third']).astype(object) # Create empty columns of "object" type    
df[['first', 'second', 'third']] = df.text.apply(parse)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast 
to indexing result of shape (3,2)
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:**

I should clarify that `parse()` itself is a much more complicated function in the real-world problem I'm trying to solve. (it takes a paragraph, finds 3 specific types of strings in it, and outputs those strings as a list of length 3). In my code above, I made up a somewhat random simple definition of `parse()` as a substitute to avoid getting bogged down in details unrelated to the two errors I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['alpha', 'beta'], columns = ['text'])

for i in ['first', 'second', 'third']:
    df[i] = df.text + '-' + i

#     text       first       second       third
# 0  alpha  alpha-first  alpha-second  alpha-third
# 1   beta   beta-first   beta-second   beta-third
```

In general the hierarchy of "process type" to choose for your calculations should be:

1. Vectorised calculations, such as above.
2. `pd.Series.apply`
3. `pd.DataFrame.apply`
4. `pd.DataFrame.iterrows`

Comment: Thanks, I learned something from your last statement. But I have questions. First, how is using a regular for-loop vectorized? I thought explicit loops were the very slowest (or tied for slowest) process type?

Second, assume the function I am applying is arbitrary. All you know about it is it takes one string and outputs a list of three strings. (please see my EDIT in the original post, which was after your reply).

Comment: (1) Using a regular `for` loop is not vectorised. Using `pandas` in-built functionality, e.g. `df.text + '-' + i` is vectorised. (2) You are right, my 4th option, `df.iterrows`, is an explicit loop and it is slowest. (3) If your function is complex and not vectorisable, then `pd.Series.apply` or `pd.DataFrame.apply` is your best bet. Which one depends on how much data you need for your function (data from one column or all columns for each row).

Comment: Ok re: (2) and (3). Re: (1), the vectorized `pandas` functionality you used was still wrapped in an explicit `for` loop. Doesn't that count as a slow process then? Is it ok only because the loop itself iterates over only 3 columns while the code inside it implicitly iterates over (potentially) thousands or millions of rows? Just trying to reach full understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @gnotnek, i'm confused, where's the "vectorized pandas functionality you used was still wrapped in an explicit for loop" - no `for` loop in my code above!

Comment: `for i in ['first', 'second', 'third']:` is an explicit `for` loop, right?

Comment: @gnotnek, have to differentiate between looping columns & looping rows. Looping 3 columns has insignificant cost. What I was talking about is looping rows (e.g. looping through 1mio rows to populate a column). The former is OK, the latter expensive.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was suspecting and you made it very clear now. I'm fairly new to coding so this really helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a several ways:

**Option 1:**

```
def f(s):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s, 3).values.reshape(len(s), -1),
                        columns=['first','second','third']) \
             .apply(lambda c: c+'-'+c.name)


In [183]: df[['first','second','third']] = f(df.text)

In [184]: df
Out[184]:
    text        first        second        third
0  alpha  alpha-first  alpha-second  alpha-third
1   beta   beta-first   beta-second   beta-third
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking more for a clarification of why I'm even getting these errors and a very minimal tweak of my code, not a wholesale change. I'm having some difficulty parsing your function since it's all one statement. Also please see my "EDIT" above re: the function itself being arbitrary, which I believe I made after your post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner with `pd.DataFrame.assign`:

```
df.assign(**{x: df['text']+'-'+x for x in ['first', 'second', 'third']})

#     text        first        second        third
# 0  alpha  alpha-first  alpha-second  alpha-third
# 1   beta   beta-first   beta-second   beta-third
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
lst = ['text','first','second','third']
df = pd.DataFrame([['alpha']*len(lst),['beta']*len(lst)],columns=lst)

final = df.apply(lambda x: x+'-'+x.name)
final.text = final.text.str.split('-')[0]
```